# How to create a div which disappears after a time, but hovering will keep it?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, embedded-ruby

I am trying to create a notification which will pop up, then disappear after a few seconds, but I want the user to be able to hover over it with the mouse to keep it from disappearing. If I could I'd like to also have a click make it disappear, but that's not necessary. I'm not sure how I could have the hover in html interact with the embedded ruby to stop the timeout. I'm aware I might need to restructure the whole thing to make it work. Here's the relevant css and html/erb snippets (not enough to run):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#alert_box').fadeOut('fast');
}, 3000);
```

```css
.alert_wrap {
  padding: 0px 50px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
  border: 3px solid red;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<% unless notice == nil %>
<div id="alert_box" class="alert_wrap">
  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var myTimeOut = setTimeout("mytimeoutfunction()", 3000);
$('#alert_box').mouseout( function () {
  myTimeOut = setTimeout("mytimeoutfunction()", 3000)
});

$('#alert_box').mouseover( function () {
  clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
});

var mytimeoutfunction = function () {
  $('#alert_box').fadeOut('fast');
}

// On click, fadeout
$("#close").click(mytimeoutfunction);
```

```css
.alert_wrap {
 padding: 0px 50px;
 margin-top: 3px;
 height: 5%;
 background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
 border: 3px solid red;
 grid-row-start: 2;
 justify-self: center;
}
#alert_box {
  position: relative;
}
#close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="alert_box" class="alert_wrap">
 <p class="notice">This is notice text</p>
 <p class="alert">This is alert text</p>
    <span id="close">X</span>
</div>
```

In the first step you can use `setTimeout` and then on `mouseover` or `hover` event, you can clear the timeout function using [`clearTimeout`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) and thus the `fadeout` will not take effect.

And on `mouseout` you can again use the `setTimeout` to start counting for 3 seconds.

Also since you have mentioned about the click event, I have added a close button that on click can call the timeout function straight away.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot. But it should be `setTimeout(mytimeoutfunction, 3000);` instead of `setTimeout("mytimeoutfunction()", 3000);`. And consequentially the function needs to be defined before

Answer (score 1):

You could approach it with CSS animations:

```css
.alert_wrap {
  padding: 0px 50px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  height: 5%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
  border: 3px solid red;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  animation: alert 4s linear none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes alert {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.alert_wrap:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert_wrap">
  <p>Some alert</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may also work, but I would probably do this with CSS transitions (again using :not(:hover) pseudo selector)

```js
var handler = setInterval(hideBox, 100); // interval function

function hideBox() {
  if ($('.alert_wrap:not(:hover)').length) { // check if the alert is visible and not hovered
    setTimeout(function() { // after 3 seconds
      if ($('.alert_wrap:not(:hover)').length) { // if not hovered yet
        $('.alert_wrap:not(:hover)').fadeOut('fast');
        clearInterval(handler);
        handler = 0;
      }
    }, 3000);    
  }
}
```